# SingletonBeanFactoryLocator cannot find XML files located in another JAR

Tags: spring

Somehow, project A cannot read project B's **spring.xml** and **spring-database.xml** files.

Project B is inside the same APP-INF/lib of the EAR Project A is in.

**Project A**

application-myproject-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
<bean id="examples.spring" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
<constructor-arg>
<list>
<value>examples/spring/**spring.xml**</value>
<value>examples/spring/**spring-database.xml**</value>
</list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
</beans>
```

client code…

```
BeanFactoryLocator bfLocator = SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.getInstance();
BeanFactoryReference bfReference = bfLocator.useBeanFactory("examples.spring");
BeanFactory factory = bfReference.getFactory();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) factory.getBean("dataSource");
```

**Project B**

```
spring.xml
spring-database.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'classpath' keyword :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
<bean id="examples.spring" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
<constructor-arg>
<list>
<value>classpath:/examples/spring/spring.xml</value>
<value>classpath:/examples/spring/spring-database.xml</value>
</list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Assuming that the `spring.xml` and `spring-database.xml` files are located in the B.jar file under directory `examples/spring`